# ipad 3 - openGL bug with kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking and retina?

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es

i have an iOS openGL app which uses the kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking property to draw the current frame on top of the previous frame. it's a cheap way of getting effects like motion trails.

it works great on all devices (including iPhone w/ retina) and all device simulators, but on the actual iPad 3 device, the previous frame is vertically squished to 75% of its previous size.

for example, if i were to draw a 100 x 100 square at the bottom of the screen each frame,
then in frame 0 i have one square, in frame 2 there's an echo that's 100 x 75 and offset towards the top of the screen, in frame three there's an additional echo that's 100 x 56 (56 ~= 75 * 0.75) and is more offset towards the top, and so-on. what *should* happen is that all the echoes remain in place.

i've verified the behavior on two devices, so i don't think it's a just a broken iPad.

any ideas ?

tia,
orion

Comment: just realized that 1536 = 2048*0.75,
which suggests to me that somewhere, some system is using the image width for both width and height.

Comment: i've been able to repro this with apple's example openGL app from xcode 4.0.1, and it's clearly a bug in the device. filed w/ apple as bug # 11069618.

Comment: I can confirm this bug (which only appears on actual Retina iPad hardware), and have filed another bug report on it with a sample project that illustrates the issue.

Comment: Ugh. It looks like this bug is impacting Layers for iPad. I'm investigating a workaround... I'll keep y'all posted.

Comment: I was able to work around it by rendering to a texture myself, which is really a more robust solution in the long run. the only tricky part is allocating the texture to be the appropriate power-of-two dimensions and then rendering to a sub-portion of it. for what it's worth, apple has confirmed the bug and says it's under investigation as bug # 11070429.

Comment: Thanks orion—Layers uses this technique to redraw only the affected portion of the screen when you're creating a new brush stroke and I'd really rather not redraw the whole canvas—but it looks like that may be the only short-term solution if it's a legit bug.

Comment: I'm seeing similar issues trying to upgrade iBeams and gravilocity to use the retina display. I render to a pair of OpenGL fbos and then flip between them. The code that worked fine for the 4/4s only gets me 25% of the frame.

Comment: @orionelenzil You do not need power of two textures if you call `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);` and `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);` before your call to `glTexImage2D`. This should make your code simpler and more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

I was seeing this bug. I don’t know anything about OpenGL, so I couldn’t really dig into solving it with textures, as has been suggested, but in my case I was able to switch to a very fast implementation of Quartz 2D drawing based on a tutorial from http://blog.effectiveui.com/?p=8105, plus how to make it work on Retina from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10870188/255489. It actually ended up being much faster than the code I had borrowed from Apple’s GLPaint sample code.

Answer (score 1):

This was a confirmed bug with retained backing and the Retina iPad in iOS 5.x. It has since been fixed in iOS 6.0 and higher.

Comment: yes; i can also confirm that this is fixed on iPad retina w/ iOS 6.