# Problems displaying full-screen CAEAGLLayer on Retina iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es, retina-display

I've run into some problems getting a UIView with a large CAEAGLLayer to display properly.  If the frame is above a certain size (apparently 768 in either dimension with a contentScaleFactor of 2.0), it redraws with a distorted image of previous versions of the buffer.

It's pretty easy to reproduce in Apple's GLPaint example.  PaintingView.m has a hardcoded contentScaleFactor of 1.0, but if you change it to 2.0:

```
self.contentScaleFactor = 2.0;
```

and run it on a Retina iPad (not the simulator), you get something like this when you draw:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuJT8.jpg

Comment: iOS 5.1.1 is released, but it looks like this issue hasn't been fixed on my "iPad 3" retina display. Hmmmm....

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be a bug with setting `kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking` to YES on the Retina iPads, as reported by Orion in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753230/ipad-3-opengl-bug-with-keagldrawablepropertyretainedbacking-and-retina). Setting that to NO using

```
    eaglLayer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking, kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat, nil];
```

removes the glitched drawing, but GLPaint relies on the retained backing for its brushes, so it won't work quite right if you do so.

I've filed a bug report on this (rdar://11070429), with the modified GLPaint as a test application for this behavior.

Comment: Thanks Brad, i'm creating a painting app based on GLPaint, am i to understand that i can not support drawing for iPad3 retina display? (BTW - GPUImage is amazing, tnx!)

Comment: @YogevShelly - There are ways of doing this, but you'll need to modify GLPaint to use a different drawing process (rendering to texture, for example). GLPaint really is a terrible example to start from if you're not familiar with OpenGL ES, so you're almost better off writing your own drawing application from scratch.

Comment: Setting kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking to NO results in an animated Ant-Trail effect. so for now i should just forget about CAEAGLLayer and look into other openGL painting methods? (i'm not experienced in openGL)

Comment: @BradLarson is quickly becoming the John Skeet of the iOS world

Comment: Hi guys, is this still an issue in iOS 6?