# ipad3 kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking bug -- fixed in ios 6?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, uiviewcontroller, ios6

Referencing the known bug with kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking as described here:

[ipad 3 - openGL bug with kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking and retina?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753230/ipad-3-opengl-bug-with-keagldrawablepropertyretainedbacking-and-retina)

Has anyone tried this in iOS 6?  I'm hitting this bug.  I'm deciding if I should just wait for iOS 6 to release this app, or go ahead and implement a workaround;  don't want to implement a workaround...

Anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, answered my own question:  YES!  Tried my app in iOS 6, latest beta, and it works as expected.